# drop event for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

i want to get an external file via the drop event. I overwrote the default event like this:

```
    $(document).on("dragover drop", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
```

which works fine.

but when i add a new `drop` event it doesn't fire

```
$('div#dropzone').on("drop", function(e) {
   console.log("drop");
   console.log(e.dataTransfer.files);
}
```

Comment: Is this really actual code or you just did some typos here.

Comment: what version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: right now IE9, but i also want to make it work on IE8

Comment: it seems that he can't find the Element

Comment: there shouldn't be any typos left ...